# Infinite scrolling in home page of a social media App using react Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble in adding Infinite Scrolling in my Home.js to display posts. If i display all the posts directly then on each refresh a no of read counts are added to my database(Firebase). I want to limit a display to `10-12` posts and display next according to the scrolling. How and where to add the infinite scrolling code and on what to add. Here is my static Home.js. On the code below all the posts are being displayed directly:

```
function Home() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [modalStyle] = useState(getModalStyle);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [openSignIn, setOpenSignIn] = useState(false);
  const [username, setUserName] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [user, setUser] = useState('null');
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
    const [url, setUrl] = useState("");


  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
       if (authUser){
         console.log(authUser);
         setUser(authUser);
     
      }
      else {
        setUser(null)

    }
  })
  return() =>{
    unsubscribe(); 
  }

  }, [user, username]);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('posts').orderBy('timestamp','desc').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc =>({
        id: doc.id,
       post: doc.data()
      })));
    })

  }, [])

  return (

    <div className="app">
    
     <div className="app_header">

       <img className="app_headerImage"
       src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/inconnect-b0ef1.appspot.com/o/dp%2FLOGO786.png?alt=media&token=adeb1a58-5085-4a3f-b33a-9b6d8078624c"
       />
       
       
         <div className="app_loginContainer">
           <Button onClick={() => auth.signOut()}><Link to='/' >Logout </Link><BsHouseDoorFill/> </Button>
            <a>
            
           <Button > <Link to='/Feed' > Feed</Link> <BsHouseDoorFill/> </Button>
           <Button ><Link to='/Profile' > Profile</Link> <BsHouseDoorFill/> </Button>
           
           <br>
           </br>
           <br>
           </br>
           <Avatar
            className="post_avatar"
            alt='inconnect'
            src="https://i2-prod.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article6393590.ece/ALTERNATES/s615/Daniel-Craig-in-a-new-photoshoot-to-announce-the-release-of-tickets-Bond-film-Spectre.jpg"
            /><h3>Hi {user.displayName}! </h3>
           </a>
         </div> 
  
     </div>
     {user?.displayName ? (
     <Modal className="photodiv"
        open={open}
        
        onClose={() => setOpen(false)}>
          <div  style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>

         
          <ImageUpload username={user.displayName} />
  

      
    </div>
     
       
      </Modal>
      ):
      ( <h3>Sorry you need to login to upload and comment</h3>

      )}


     <div className="topload">

         <h1  onClick={() => setOpen(true)}> Wanna post {user.displayName}?</h1>
     </div>
     <Search />
     <div className="app_posts">
        <div className="app_postsLeft">

          {
             posts.map(({id, post}) =>(
             <Post key={id} postId={id} user= {user} username={post.username} caption={post.caption} imageUrl={post.imageUrl}/>
              
             ))
          }
        </div>
        
         </div>

    </div>
      
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Intersection observer
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API
Create component and emit events 'show' or 'hide' - depend on whether observer interacts viewport or not
Sorry, for my bad English, but I hope, you cought me)